# AngularJS - "import" different JS files from HTML

Tags: html, dom, angularjs, import, scope

I was trying to import certain script depending on which URL I'm.

Simple `<script>` tag in my HTML is:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{srcRoute}}" language="JavaScript"></script>
...
</html>
```

I was trying to get this after main module "myApp", in a run block:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
      .config(function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.
           when('/', {controller: MyController, templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'}).
           otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
      })
      .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.srcRoute = 'some/route/here.js';
    });
```

but when running this I get something like:

```
GET myRoute/%7B%7BsrcRoute%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

What I want to do is add a conditional sentence in the run block to decide which route to use. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The browser looks like it's trying to grab the file before Angular has had time to interpolate the value of `{{srcRoute}}`. This makes sense because the app is not bootstrapped until the document is ready, which includes loading any scripts. With `<img>` tags you are encouraged to use `<img ng-src="{{expression}}"/>` to avoid this problem. See if that works here too?

Comment: Hi @cmw. I tried as you suggested but it is not trying to get the script file, it remains as {{expression}} and I'm not getting  the (Not Found) error message.